# print_slow crashing, how to fix?

Tags: python

I wrote this function `print_slow` and add it into the following, but when I use it in the code it closes the command prompt or terminal.

How should I fix this?

```
def print_slow(text):
    for each in text:
        print(each, end='', flush=True)
        sleep(0.1)
```

I have it running in this:

```
while keep_running:
    print("press ctrl+c to exit.")
 
username = str(input("username:"))
    if username.upper() == "":
        print_slow("welcome ! please insert your last name to complete this login and get to celebrating!")
        password = str(input("last name:"))
        if password.upper() == "":
            print_slow( '''\
         Its you!!! YAY!!! Happy fathers day!
         how is your day going?
         mine is going well.
         I'm told your a great father.
         uh, do you want to exit?\
            ''')
            # print("Its you!!! YAY!!! Happy fathers day!")
            # print("how is your day going?")
            # print("mine is going well.")
            # print("I'm told your a great father.")
            # print("uh, do you want to exit?")
            do_you = str(input("Y/N:"))
            if (do_you.upper() == "YES") | (do_you.upper() == "Y") | (do_you.upper() == "YE"):
                print_slow ("oh, I will let you go now. bye.")
                sleep(1)
                kee_prunning=0
            if (do_you.upper() == "NO") | (do_you.upper() == "N") | (do_you.upper() == "NO!"):
                print_slow("cool, uuh I don't know what to say.")
                print_slow("huh")
                sleep(2)
                keep_running = 0
        else:
            print_slow("Did you guess the first one?!?")
            sleep(3)
            keep_running = 0
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: this question essentially can't be answered in it's current state - we'd at least have to know what `text` is

Comment: `text` is a string

Comment: You should correctly format your code, and ensure that someone can copy paste it in it's entirety and run it

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: had you import sleep from time module

Answer (score 1):

**It's the missed indentation at the `username` input line that caused the crash.**

*(note: You don't need to convert input statements with `str()`)*.

Try this:

```
from time import sleep

def print_slow(text):
    for each in text:
        print(each,end='',flush=True)
        sleep(0.1)

keeprunning = True

while keeprunning:
    print ("press ctrl+c to exit.")
    username = input("username:") # You missed an indent here
    if username.upper() == "":
        print_slow("welcome ! please insert your last name to complete this login and get to celebrating!")
        password = input("last name:")
        if password.upper() == "":
            print_slow( '''\
         Its you!!! YAY!!! Happy fathers day!
         how is your day going?
         mine is going well.
         I'm told your a great father.
         uh, do you want to exit?\
            ''')
            #print ("Its you!!! YAY!!! Happy fathers day!")
            #print ("how is your day going?")
            #print("mine is going well.")
            #print("I'm told your a great father.")
            #print ("uh, do you want to exit?")
            doyou = input("Y/N: ")
            if (doyou.upper() == "YES") | (doyou.upper() == "Y") | (doyou.upper() == "YE"):
                print_slow ("oh, I will let you go now. bye.")
                sleep(1)
                keeprunning=0
            if (doyou.upper() == "NO") | (doyou.upper() == "N") | (doyou.upper() == "NO!"):
                print_slow ("cool, uuh I don't know what to say.")
                print_slow ("huh")
                sleep(2)
                keeprunning=0
        else:
            print_slow ("Did you guess the first one?!?")
            sleep(3)
            keeprunning = 0
```

Comment: I have the indents because I have a `while true:`

Comment: thanks but your code here is the same as mine in visual studios

Comment: Try copy and pasting my code see if there is any difference.

Comment: so I tried that and it still crashed. is there a way I can find what made it crash?

Comment: was there a point when you coded it that you tested it and it didn't crash?

Comment: yes I would input the user name and password at the time and it would work, today when I changed it to print_slow it would crash